# python setup.py: how to set the path for the generated .so

Tags: python, c, distutils, setup.py

I have this setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from setuptools import setup, Extension
import numpy as np

module1 = Extension('filename',
                    sources = ['utilities/filename.c'])

setup (name = 'library',
       version = '1.0',
       description = 'library',
       include_dirs = [np.get_include()],
       ext_modules = [module1])
```

I want to create the filename.so into the folder utilities.
I tried with

```
python setup.py build -f --build-temp=. -e utilities/
```

but this put only the filename.o file into utilities/ and the .so into build/lib...

Any idea? Is it possible or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want extensions modules to be build in the same directory you could use this:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

Or you can add this parameter to specify a build folder

```
--build-lib=folderx
```

Answer (score 1):

To build up on [@J.Serra's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32224869/5446749), you can also create a `setup.cfg` file and write inside either:

```ini
[build_ext]
inplace=1
```

or

```ini
[build_ext]
build-lib=./path/to/folder/
```